# SwiftUI: Switching from @State to @Binding causes compilation error

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and still learning so this maybe obvious.  The difference between the two is changing from @State to @Binding.  There is clearly magic happening that was working for the first case but not working for the second case.  Any insights greatly received.

Compiles fine:

```
struct PointEditorView: View {
  @State var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float> = 3...8

  var body: some View {
     Text("PointEditorView")
  }
}
```

Fails to compile:

```
struct PointEditorView: View {
  @Binding var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float> = 3...8

  var body: some View {
     Text("PointEditorView")
  }
}
```

This second case results in two errors:

1. Incorrect argument label in call (have 'wrappedValue"; expected 'projectedValue:'
2. Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRanged to specified type 'Binding<ClosedRange>'

Comment: Do you understand what a `Binding` is? What would `@Binding var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float> = 3...8` even *mean*?

Comment: A `Binding` would never have an initialized value like this. You would pass a binding in from something else.

Comment: Binding is a two way connection it doesn’t need a value of it’s own it comes from the parent. You should try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your second piece of code is because `@Binding` works differently than `@State`. While `@State` creates and owns the data, `@Binding` does not - its meant to be a reference to data owned by another part of your app, in your case the `PointEditorView` is the owner

To fix the second example, you need to pass the sliderPosition as a Binding from a parent view, like this:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @State private var sliderPosition: Float = 3.0

    var body: some View {
        PointEditorView(sliderPosition: $sliderPosition)
    }
}

struct PointEditorView: View {
    @Binding var sliderPosition: Float

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(sliderPosition.description)
            Slider(value: $sliderPosition, in: 3...8)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `ParentView` owns the state and passes a binding reference to PointEditorView. I placed it in a VStack so that we can vertically stack the Views and see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the language is concerned, this is just how property wrappers (`@State`, `@Binding` and others) work.

```
@Foo var foo: SomeType = bar
```

declares 2 or 3 properties all at once. It lowers to:

```
private var _foo = Foo(wrappedValue: bar)
var foo: SomeType { 
    get { _foo.wrappedValue }
    set { _foo.wrappedValue = newValue }
}

// only when Foo has a projectedValue property
var $foo: AnotherType { 
    get { _foo.projectedValue }
    set { _foo.projectedValue = newValue }
}
```

A stored property storing an instance of the property wrapper itself, and computed properties wrapping `wrappedValue` and `projectedValue`.

Notice how the stored property is initialised. This requires the property wrapper to have an initialiser taking a single parameter, with the parameter label `wrappedValue:`. [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) has [such an initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/init(wrappedvalue:)). [`@Binding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) does not.

`@Binding` does have [an initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(projectedvalue:)) with a single parameter label `projectedValue:`, taking another `Binding`. That's why the confused compiler emits errors saying the parameter label is incorrect, and that the argument cannot be converted to `Binding`.

If you remove the initialiser from the declaration:

```
@Binding var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float>
```

Then `_sliderPosition` will not be initialised with `Binding(wrappedValue: ...)` (which is invalid), and so there is no problem. This generates a memberwise initialiser that takes a `Binding` and initialises `_sliderPosition` to the initialiser parameter.

Recommended reading: [Initialization of synthesized storage properties](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#initialization-of-synthesized-storage-properties) section of the Swift Evolution Proposal for property wrappers.

---

From a SwiftUI point of view, `Binding` represents a "binding" to some source of truth (or another `Binding`), like a `@State` property, a `@Published` property of an `ObservableObject`, etc. A `@Binding` property is designed to be uninitialised, so that parent views can make a `Binding` that binds to some state of the parent, and pass it to the child.

If you want a `Binding` that wraps a constant value, use `Binding.constant(...)`. You do not need the property wrapper.

```
let sliderPosition: Binding<ClosedRange<Float>> = .constant(3...8)
```